# Element not visible with button click in selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exception, button, visible

I'm trying to click the continue button after filling in the fields on this webpage. But an exception is thrown saying element is not visible even though I maximize the screen and you can clearly see the button.

I have tried the following even with waiting 10 seconds for the page:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"submitButton\"]/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submitButton > span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Continue")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("caret_rebrand")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("submitButton")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'red') and contains(text(), 'Continue')]")).click();
```

Here is the part of the html I am trying to access:

```
<button style="padding-left: 0px;" type=button" "id=submitButton" class = "nbutton" title = "Continue" onclick=_hblicnk('continue,'continue'); goFeaturePage('true');">
 <span style = "padding-right: 12px;" class="red"
      "Continue"
      <img class="caret_rebrand">
 </span>
```

I expect the continue button to be found and clicked. [attached is the picture of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtDj1.png)

**UPDATE: 8-3-19: I've tested the following pieces of code and it is able to find the element in all cases. But when adding the .click() function to any one of them, it causes a no such element exception.**

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submitButton")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submitButton")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"submitButton\"]")).click();
```

Comment: Check if the button is present in a iframe.

Comment: There are 2 iframe elements in the javascript and I am getting this error.  org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //button[@title='Continue (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: When you say there are two iframes, if this button is under any one of the iframe then you need to switch to that iframe first and then try to perform operation on the button.

Comment: I've tested the button in all iframes and the click is not working causing a no such element exception. When I run the following codes, it can find the element without the iframe, but when adding the .click() function, then it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

1. My expectation is that you need to click the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element as this [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) might be not clickable at all. You can use i.e. [title](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp) attribute to uniquely identify the element on the page
2. It's better to use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to ensure that the button is present and clickable as it might be the case it's not available in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) right away. Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more details
3. Assuming all above I believe you should be able to use below code for clicking the button:

   ```
   continue_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Continue']")))
   continue_button.click()
   ```

Comment: I tried using your method and it gave me this exception. org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //button[@title='Continue (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)